# How to update campaigns content with template in mailchimp

Tags: templates, mailchimp

I want to use mailchimp to send mail when something happen automatically  , so i use mailchimp restful api to do this:

```
1.Create a campaign with api /campaigns
2.Update the campaign with api /campaigns/{campaign_id}/content
3.Send the campaign
```

in this second step, i found the API /campaigns/{campaign_id}/content can update the campaign's content with plaintext or html easy with http body like this:

`{"html": "<p>The HTML to use for the saved campaign<./p>"}`

but i am not sure how to use a template to update the content.
In the API document(https://developer.mailchimp.com/documentation/mailchimp/reference/campaigns/content/#), if you want to use template update content, you need fill the template id and template sections, but how do i know the sections in a template?

I try to use the template api to get a template detail information, in the response, the section filed is empty array.

any suggestion? or give me example!

thank you guys

Regard to great developers

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you ever found an answer, but I am struggling with this API too. The sections can be retrieve from the GetDefaultContent API which will return an MailChimp Response with a sections object. That object, in turn, will have all the sections that you have specified in your template by name and their default content.

I am still trying to figure out the updating part, myself, but hope this helps a bit.

Comment: How is this an answer?

Comment: Well, given that at least in part, the question was "how do I know the sections in a template" I responded with the method call that will return a listing of the sections. I assume the tone of your comment was born from the same frustration that the original poster, and myself, felt trying to create a solution with the Mail Chimp API. I have worked my way to a few solutions since then and will be happy to share my knowledge if you would like to ask some questions.